# Default argument for a functor in a templated parameter

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, c++17, template-argument-deduction

I would like to have a default lambda for a functor argument in my function.

I am aware it is possible using a `struct` and `operator()` like this:

```
struct AddOne {
    int operator()(int a) {
        return a+1;
    }
};

template <typename Functor = AddOne>
int run_old(int x, Functor func = AddOne()) 
{
    return func(x);
}
```

But I was wondering if there was a modern way, given the changes in the standard in either c++14/17/20, to make this work?

```
template <typename Functor>
int run_new(int x, Functor func = [](int a){ return a+1; }) 
{
    return func(x);
}
```

I'm not sure what one would use as the default type to Functor, or if there is syntax i'm unaware of.

https://godbolt.org/z/Hs6vQs

Comment: "*modern way*" What's wrong with the old way? The struct method is much easier to read at the function site.

Comment: In the _old way_, you likely don't want to provide both default template and function arguments this way: https://wandbox.org/permlink/PtSwiQwsNDyDrshu. Use `Functor func = Functor()` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From *C++11* you can already do that:

```
template <typename Functor = int(int)>
int run_new(int x, Functor func = [](int a){ return a+1; }) 
{
    return func(x);
}
```

Comment: works only with non-capturing lambda, no? (not relevant for the question as asked)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: If you pass a capturing lambda, then the template function will deduce the type of this lambda, thus overriding the default type of `int(int)`.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I don't think you can capture anything in this context since the lambda is used as a default argument.

Comment: @BiagioFesta oh right ;) maybe some globals but I dont care about them

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 You couldn't capture a global anyway. Capturing requires *automatic* storage.

Comment: Note that GCC and Clang are smart enough to inline the lambda call even though it gets converted into a function pointer. https://godbolt.org/z/nl4qEj

Answer (score 3):

Just add an overload for this.

```
template <typename Functor>
int run_new(int x, Functor func) 
{
    return func(x);
}

int run_new(int x) 
{
    return run_new(x, [](int a){ return a+1; });
}
```

Allows you to get around not beening able to have a lambda expression as a default function argument.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite "modern" but you could use plain old overloading with a non-template method taking only a single parameter:

```
int run_new(int x) 
{
    return func(x,[](int a){ return a+1;});  // calls the template overload
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, in C++20 we have both (1) lambdas in unevaluated contexts and (2) lambdas without capture are default constructible. Combine those two and you get:

```
template <typename Functor = decltype([](int a){ return a+1; })>
int run_new(int x, Functor func = {})
{
    return func(x);
}
```

[Obligatory godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/d1wj13).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to other questions, you can even avoid templates:

```
int run_new(int x, std::function<int(int)> func = [](int a){ return a + 1; })
{
   return func(x);
}
```

Comment: Do note that you do incur a cost for this.  `std::function` uses type erasure so you have dynamic allocation and more than likely lose the ability to inline the code.

Comment: @NathanOliver Both GCC and Clang seem to be smart enough to generate the same inlined assembly code for `f`, which is minimal: https://godbolt.org/z/uuEeNE. Need to admit I was surprised.

Comment: @DanielLangr But now the functor has to be copyable

Comment: @Artyer That's the drawback. The advantage is that you don't need to expose the function definition in a header file.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can imagine pass through a variable

```
static constexpr auto defFunc = [](int a){ return a+1; };

template <typename Functor = decltype(defFunc)>
int run_new(int x, Functor func = defFunc) 
{
    return func(x);
}
```